# Select the most recent entries with different IDs in mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, timestamp

So, I have 2 tables.

**Table:** Measuremements

PersonID - Value - Timestamp - TypeID

**Table:** Measurement type

TypeID - Measurement Name

I want to display the 2 most recent entries from 2 different TypeIDs. So I need to select one Value from TypeID 1 with the most recent timestamp and one Value from TypeID 2 with the most recent timestamp. I also have to get the names of the measurements using the TypeID between the tables. And I want to limit my selection to a specific PersonID.

I have tried different ways to do this, but I just don't understand what to do.

At the moment my code is:

```
SELECT 
  m.value, 
  m.timestamp, 
  m_t.measurement_name
FROM measurements m
INNER JOIN measurement_type m_t ON m.typeid = m_t.typeid
GROUP BY m.typeid
ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

My first question, so I can try to explain it better if needed :D

Comment: What's wrong with your current code? What result do you get now?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to get the `max` timestamp for each type and then `join` the result back to itself:

```
select m.typeid, m.value, m.timestamp, mt.measurement_name
from measurements m
    join (select max(timestamp) maxtimestamp, typeid
          from measurements 
          group by typeid) m2 on m.timestamp = m2.maxtimestamp
                             and m.typeid = m2.typeid
    join measurement_type mt on m.typeid = mt.typeid
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this works just as I needed, been fighting this problem forever, you saved my day :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to get the most recent entry for given type id:

```
select m.personID, m.value, m.typeID, mt.measurement_name
from measurements m join measurements_type mt on m.typeID = mt.typeID
where m.typeID = ?
order by m.timestamp desc limit 1;
```

Comment: This works also, but because I want most recent entry from all 6 types and only one entry per type, the other solution works a little better, but thank you anyway, this helped me understand SQL a lot better :D